# how to prevent other people's comments from being deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

yesterday (12-jun-2017) I posted 2 questions and none of them was answered directly, however, the comments people posted were very useful and they enlighted me to do what I needed to do with confidence.

[troubleshooting login failure when AD group seems to be fine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176079/troubleshooting-login-failure-when-ad-group-seems-to-be-fine?noredirect=1#comment341066_176079)

[what are points to consider when replacing the sql server service account?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176077/what-are-points-to-consider-when-replacing-the-sql-server-service-account)

I am very thankful for the people who posted such comments, and I want to keep those comments there, even in the case someone wants to delete them, or even leave this forum.

questions:

upvoting the comment is the right way to show gratitude?

what can I do to perpetuate those comments there, even in the event some of those lovely users decide to leave the DBA world including this forum?

I was thinking I could add an asnwer myself including all those comments and links, or editing the question adding a conclusion with all that info.
either case I would also add what solved the issues in my particular case.
only problem, today I am busy with other unrelated issues....
would this be a good thing? I am not sure, hence the question.

Comment: I don't think comments with useful *and relevant* info would get deleted before someone recaptured them in their post (or edited them in to someone else's). Answering in comments is certainly against the spirit or format of the site but I really doubt a mod would drop a comment solely because it was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do anything about the actual comments. Comments may get flagged, they may get deleted. In a way, all comments are eventually deleted.

If the comments are useful though and helped you in your issue, you can write an answer based on them and include advice and links. You can also attribute the advice to the users.

Regarding "I don't have much time" and whether *"I should gather them in an answer"*:

Yes, you should! It won't take you more than a minute to copy paste the useful comments in an answer with a list. Example:

> Answer based on very useful comments:
>
> - [@user_a](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1) : *You could use this tutorial: http://useful_tutorial.help.xyz*
> - [@johnny](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1) : Just drop the whole table and recreate!.
> - [@xyz](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1) : this could have been avoided if you have done X.
>
> In the end, I went and did X, Y and Z.

You have the option to mark the answer as *"Community Wiki"* if you like. Most users will find it less intrusive to edit a CW post - and edit any errors or add more comments.

Comment: Bonus points for "mark the answer as _"Community Wiki"_ if you like".